# Comma separate custom taxonomies (no links)

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's just a simple little question I can't seem to figure out. I have one custom taxonomy which has multiple options. But I want to show the taxonomies without links. So I use this code:

```
<li>
    <?php
        $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'opties');

        if (!empty($terms_as_text)) echo '', strip_tags($terms_as_text) , '';
    ?>
</li>
```

This display's only the selected custom taxonomies of `opties`. Because this taxonomy has multiple options I would like to comma separate them. But it won't let me.

Normally you would use:

`<?php
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'opties', '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>`

- The first part = before.
- The middle part = separate.
- The last part = after.

But this makes links of the custom taxonomy terms, and I don't want that to happen.

But because of the `strip_tags($terms_as_text)` I can't comma separate them.

How can I get them to separate with a comma?

Comment: How does `echo 'before', 'separate', 'after'` relate to your question? Could you rephrase that in terms of *$terms_as_text*? Can you give an concrete example of  what *$terms_as_text* would be equal to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
global $post;
$opties = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'opties', array("fields" => "names"));
if (count($opties) > 0)
{
    echo implode(', ', $opties);
}
```

Comment: Or I'm doing something wrong... But it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Steggie possible reasons would be. 1. No `global $post;` before the call. 2. Incorrect taxonomy slug 3. No terms for this taxonomy are attached to this specific post your checking

Comment: You Mr. Made my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
try this


$list =   get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'opties'); 
        $terms ="";
         $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $list, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
{ 

foreach($matches as $match)
{
$terms .= $match[3].","; // Get Text Only //nolinks
} 
}

echo rtrim($terms,","); // display and remove extra ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( is_singular( 'custom_post_type' ) ) {
    get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'custom_post_type_name', '', ', ' );
  }
  elseif( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    get_the_category_list( ', ', '', get_the_ID() ) . '';
  }
```

The above will return categories or custom post taxonomies with comma separated and a link to the response category or taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get the category or term without link is to use `strip_tags()` function as follow:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'category_name' ));?>
```